# Insert form data into mysql database table using node.js and express implicitly?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I tried to do something like this the below code inserts explicitly what is the alternative when i want to insert dynamically.

When i tried the Query like this am able to insert into a table

```
var post  = {id:'20', name: 'cool', password:'****'};
        var do = con.query('INSERT INTO  fuck SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
           if (err) throw err;
        else res.send('success');
        });
```

But when i directly inserting the form values to table the table is not getting updated

```
app.post('/getData',function(req, res, next){
        var txtname = req.body.name;
        var ager = req.body.age;
        var pwdd = req.body.pd;
      var post  = {id:ager, name: txtname, password:pwdd };
    var do = con.query('INSERT INTO  fuck SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
       if (err) throw err;
    else res.send('success');
    });
```

Comment: i cant find a code below

Comment: i updated the code :)